# В чем разница между Digest и Hash в OpenSSL?

Tags: хеширование, openssl

В различной документации для описания одних и тех же вещей (по крайней мере мне так кажется) используются то одни термин, то другой.

Есть ли между ними смысловая разница? И если есть, то какая?

Comment: Возможно, они считают что даджест - результат работы хэша, то есть хэш-функции? Хотя в OpenSSL местами бардак...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем контексте — скорее всего нет разницы.

Но при обсуждении различных тем термин "хэш" может быть не таким однозначным. Он может означать:

- хэш-функцию или алгоритм
- процесс хэширования
- результат хэширования, возвращённое хэш-функцией значение (тот самый digest)
- хэш-таблицу или контейнер на её основе

Comment: Ну вот например "Optional hash or digest algorithm from <function>openssl_get_md_methods</function>.  Defaults to SHA-1."

Comment: @rjhdby в том, что касается алгоритмов, это определённо одно и то же. Приведено, вероятно, для тех, кто слышал только один из этих терминов. Само словосочетание "digest algorithm" как нарицательное я в сколько-нибудь широком употреблении не встречал, скорее всего это реликвия прошлого.